# Not inserting values probably in dynamically UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i'm trying to create a dynamically fixtures which automatic updates using an API. The problem is it does connect the right sections with the right fixtures and the fixtures seem to duplicate in the different sections. Why is it not connecting the section date with the fixtures?

First i have an fixture array which contain all the fixtures.

```
[fixtures addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:date,@"date", time, @"time", competition_id,@"competition_id", home, @"home", away, @"away", nil]];
```

Then i have an array with contain all the dates with no duplicates ordered by date called reversedArray:

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"self" ascending:NO];
NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject: descriptor];

NSArray *reverseOrder = [dateArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];

reversedArray = [[reverseOrder reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
```

Then i have my view where i look

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{


    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 22)];
    /* Create custom view to display section header... */
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 22)];
    [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];
    [label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[reversedArray objectAtIndex:section]];
    NSString *newString = [dateString substringToIndex:[dateString length]-15];

    NSString *string =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",newString];

    [label setText:string];
    [view addSubview:label];

    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:13/255.0f green:78/255.0f blue:102/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];

    return view;
}
```

The numberOfRowsInSection method

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[reversedArray objectAtIndex:section]];

    NSLog(@"%@ = %@", [dateString substringToIndex:[dateString length]-15], [[fixtures objectAtIndex:section] valueForKey:@"date"]);

    NSArray *filteredArray = [fixtures filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date == %@",[dateString substringToIndex:[dateString length]-15]]];
    return filteredArray.count;

}
```

cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    FixtureCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[FixtureCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    cell.homeTeamLabel.text = [[fixtures objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"home" ];
    cell.awayTeamLabel.text = [[fixtures objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"away" ];

}
```

Comment: `if (cell == nil) {cell = [[FixtureCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];}` (end of bracklet), then `cell.homeTeamLabel.text`, etc. Not that your code doesn't seem to return `cell`.

Answer (score 0):

take out this code from your if sentence

```
cell.homeTeamLabel.text = [[fixtures objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"home" ];
cell.awayTeamLabel.text = [[fixtures objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"away" ];
```

you are reusing cells so the condition cell=nil will no be true always.

Also use indexPath.section for to know which data you should take for fill your cell

Comment: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Answer (score 0):

Change this method cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

   FixtureCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
if (cell == nil)
{

cell = [[FixtureCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
}
cell.homeTeamLabel.text = [[fixtures objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"home"];
cell.awayTeamLabel.text = [[fixtures objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"away"];

return cell;

}
```

Comment: This gives me unrecognized selector sent to instance.

Comment: and why indexpath.row 2 times in each cell text?

Comment: r u using custom table cell??

Answer (score 0):

Assign label values outside if (cell == nil) reuse cell Identifier not enter the loop after cell creation

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

    {

        FixtureCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[FixtureCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }
        cell.homeTeamLabel.text = [[fixtures objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"home" ];
        cell.awayTeamLabel.text = [[fixtures objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"away" ];
    return cell;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using custom cell then try this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"FixtureCell";

FixtureCell *cell = (FixtureCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FixtureCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

}         

cell.homeTeamLabel.text = [[fixtures objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"home"];
cell.awayTeamLabel.text = [[fixtures objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"away"];

return cell;
}
```